# Module Import Error , how to refresh Ipython session?

Tags: python, docker, module, ipython

I am a total newbie to python. I am using docker as my virtual environment. 
I am trying to run this line of code on ipython

```
pivot_df.to_excel(os.path.expandvars('/home/user/code.xlsx'))
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

I installed openpyxl successfully and then tried to import openpyxl again on ipython but with no success.

Will I have to refresh my ipython session for the openpyxl to work? If yes, how do I do that? Will I lose everything I ran until now if I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to reload as such, so import should work after you installed a package.

It may be related to some python path of virtual environment issue. Where you installed package in one python and ipython is running in another configuration.

Best thing is to execute `! pip install openpyxl` from ipython itself. This will make sure you install the package in correct environment. Then it should work

Comment: I tried that , it gave me this : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for openpyxl

Yes, I installed it on docker, the environment I am working on

Comment: which version of python? `import sys; sys.version`